# Skype public API - difference between Alter Call and Set Call?

Tags: skype

I am looking over the Skype public API and I am not sure what the difference between these two commands if the Skype call status is RINGING:

```
ALTER CALL 8 ANSWER
```

vs

```
SET CALL 8 STATUS INPROGRESS
```

The same goes for hanging up a call that is INPROGRESS.  Whats the difference between these two?

```
ALTER CALL 8 HANGUP
```

vs

```
SET CALL 8 STATUS FINISHED
```

Answer (score 0):

To my experience so far, there is not any difference between those two commands in terms of their effects.